# ranged for loop of variables results in returning address-reference of local variable?

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, fedora-25, ranged-loops

```
// g++ --std=c++17 test.cpp -I /usr/local/include -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_system -Wall -pedantic -Wreturn-type -Wstrict-aliasing -Wreturn-local-addr -fsanitize=address -g
// LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib ./a.out

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

class A {
public:
    fs::path path_;

    const fs::path & path() const { return path_; }
    fs::path & path() { return path_; }
};

class B {
public:
    fs::path root_path_;

    A path_2;
    A path_3;

    const fs::path & operator()() const {
        for ( const auto & path : {
            path_3.path(),
            path_2.path(),
            root_path_
        }) {
            if ( not path.empty() ) {
                return path;
            }
        }
        throw std::logic_error{"using default-constructed B"};
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    B b;
    b.root_path_ = "foo/";
    b.path_2.path() = "foo/bar";
    b.path_3.path() = "foo/baz";

    std::cout << b() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

With the above code which, as best as I am aware, appears to be valid C++. Instead, when invoked, I get garbage output.

`g++` does not initially complain, however Address Sanitizer *does*. `g++` finally complains when adding `-O2`. The warning generated is

```
test.cpp: In member function ‘const boost::filesystem::path& B::operator()() const’:
test.cpp:31:12: warning: function may return address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
     return path;
            ^~~~
test.cpp:29:3: note: declared here
   }) {
   ^
```

Note that I am using:

```
$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 25 (Twenty Five)
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.3.1 20161221 (Red Hat 6.3.1-1)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Note that I solved the *error* by using a pointer instead.

```
    const fs::path & operator()() const {
            for ( const auto * path : {
                    &path_3.path(),
                    &path_2.path(),
                    &root_path_
            }) {
                    if ( not path->empty() ) {
                            return *path;
                    }
            }
            throw std::logic_error{"using default-constructed B"};
    }
```

But, that does leave some questions in my mind:

1. why does `g++` *not* complain about the problem until `-O2` is added?
2. exactly what about my code is undefined? I would say it's well-defined: `B::operator() const` is... well... const. That should mean that the objects *used* inside it are either locals or const members. It accesses const members. It constructs a local variable `const auto &` which... should reference a const member field. Exactly what causes it to bind to temporary instead?

Comment: Why is a reference being returned in the first place?

Comment: This example is slimmed down; I am using `operator()` as a selector function to decide which member variable to use as input to another function. Why return a non-const (or especially non-const reference) when I don't need to modify it?

Comment: Returning by `const` value has general downsides. First, the caller's return value is isolated, so it doesn't matter to the function whether they modify it. Second, it inhibits RVO. Anyway, if you're using an initializer list in your real code, that's not going to end well because those require copying unless the language is eventually changed to allow moving.

Comment: For a [much shorter example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46c1aff5a5bad5ce)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. A compiler is not obligated to issue a diagnostic for undefined behavior. If the compiler can detect code that's syntactically valid, but results in undefined behavior, and then complains about it, that's just icing on top of the cake. gcc's `-O2` turns on additional optimizations, and does additional code analysis; as such gcc can sometimes detect undefined behavior only if optimizations are enabled.
2. It appears that your range iteration is over a ***temporary*** `std::initializer_list`. The range iteration variable is a reference into the initializer list. As such, the function ends up returning a reference to a temporary, which is what gcc is barking about, here. Since the temporary gets destroyed when the method returns, the method ends up returning a reference to a destroyed object. Any use of that reference comprises undefined behavior.

When you convert the temporary range to a list of pointers, you are iterating by value, and you are not returning a reference to a temporary, but rather derefencing the value in the range, which is a perfectly kosher pointer.

Pay attention to the following blurb [from here:](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

> The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of
>   the original initializer list object has ended. The storage for
>   std::initializer_list is unspecified (i.e. it could be automatic,
>   temporary, or static read-only memory, depending on the situation).

The lifetime if the initializer list bound to the range iteration ends at the conclusion of the iteration. Which includes returning from the method. As such, the initializer list no longer exists, and you just returned a dangling reference.

Comment: Perhaps it should be made clear that the `initializer_list` is storing the objects by value, not by reference (and bonus points for a blurb about why that is).

Comment: Yeah if I see something quoted from the standard that'd probably be marked my answer. I'd certainly like something more concrete. A temporary initializer list, sure... but why can't the temporary contain references to existing objects? When I try it by prepending the initializer list with an explicit type `std::initializer_list<const boost::filesystem::path&>{...}`, it errors: `/usr/include/c++/6.3.1/initializer_list:54:26: error: forming pointer to reference type ‘const boost::filesystem::path&’` because of forming an iterator to a pointer of a const-reference. Guess _that's it?

Comment: The same link I cited states that the contents of the initializer list are always "copy-initialized", which precludes them from being references. Although it should be possible to dig up the relevant bits from the standard, that's always a chore, and cppreference.com is generally considered to be "good enough" here.